# Terminal Marked "Not Executable", and owner is root. Ubuntu 14.04 Unity Desktop(Chromebook)

Tags: command-line, unity, permissions, chromebook

So for some reason, terminal didn't appear anywhere when I tried to find it in my applications. So I went to the usr folder in my computer, and searched "terminal" there. I found it, but it was all the way at the bottom of my applications, and had a lock icon on it's image. I tried to open it but an error came up:

```
There was an error launching that application.
```

When I checked the file permissions, it was marked as "Non-Executable". I was not able to change it to executable as it said "root" was the owner. It is probably important to mention that "UXTerm" and "XTerm" are there, and that I try to use them as an alternative. However, most commands are not likely to work. How can I change the Terminal app to executable without being the root user?

Answer (score 0):

- First press `Alt + F2` and type in `gnome-terminal`. This is the
  normal command to start terminal.
- If the terminal doesn't start then again press `Alt + F2` and type in `gksu nautilus`. Next, enter your password and move to usr and search for terminal and set it to executable.

Comment: This doesn't work ):

Comment: Where does the problem occur?

Comment: @CedaEl So I do the `gksu nautilus`  command and navigate to the terminal. I set it to executable, but it still doesn't work. Anytime I try to run it, it just says `There was an error launching the application`. Help?

Comment: Try reinstalling it

Comment: Can you log in via a tty?

Comment: A tty? What is a tty?

Comment: TTY is a virtual terminal that is started on boot using getty. In simpler words, press Ctrl + Alt + F2 . Enter your username and password. Tell me if you can login or not.